# R: Doing calculations on multiple factors/levels (Dummy variables)

Tags: r, r-factor

I have two equally long matching vectors of time series data: Price (x) and hour (h). Hour goes from 0-23. My hour variable is my dummy variable (or factor/level variable I guess it is called in R).

Right now i've defined 24 different dummy variables, and for each hour I type my dummy variable. So for example generating 24 plots to look at or calculate 24 means etc I would type:
plot.ts(hour1) # and so on for all 24.

I would like to do this for all 24 variables as easily as possible? So I can run a lot of different calculations. For example, how could I just compute the mean for all 24 dummy variables without making 24 lines of code, changing each dummy variable?

EDIT: Sorry, thought it was clear with the two vectors. Example:

```
 1. Price Hour
 2. 8     0
 3. 12    1
 4. 14    2
 5. 16    3
 6. 18    4
 7. 20    5
 8. 22    6
 9. 24    7
 10. 26   8
 11. 28   9
 12. 24   10
 13. 26   11
 14. 23   12
 15. 23   13
 16. 23   14
 17. 14   15
 18. 19   16
 19. 25   17
 20. 26   18
 21. 28   19
 22. 30   20
 23. 33   21 
 24. 24   22
 25. 10   23
 26. 14   0
 27. 12   1
 28. 13   2
 29. x    ect.
```

Comment: Even if you're perfectly clear with words the reproducible example is expected.  Often a solution is arrived at by using the tools we have and "tinkering" with the data you've got.  Often the structure of data may appear clear until you closely examine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear how your data are stored since you don't give a reproducible example. I assume you have separate variables for each hour1.

Generally, It is better to put your `hourxx` variable in a list to perform calculations.

For example, this will compute mean for all hours:

```
    lapply(lapply(ls(pattern='hour.*'),get),mean)
```

**EDIT** after OP clarification:

You shuld create a new variable to distinguish between Hours intervals. Something like :

```
dat <- data.frame(Price=rnorm(24*5),Hour=rep(0:23,5))
dat$id <- cumsum(c(0,diff(dat$Hour)==-23))
```

Then  using `ply` package for example , you can compute mean by id:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(id),summarise,mPrice=mean(Price))

 id     mPrice
1  0  0.2999602
2  1 -0.2201148
3  2  0.2400192
4  3 -0.2087594
5  4  0.1666915
```